# Why Python doesn´t save my model to database using object .save()?

Tags: python, django, database, object, save

I have a function in views.py accepting petitions that get some text and a book pk and save the text to a fragments table and update the book text with the new fragment.

The fragments are saved correctly, but the book doesn't. I get the response, but it doesn't save to the database when I manually check it.

This is my code:

```py
profilelogged = validtoken(request.META['HTTP_MYAUTH'])
    if not profilelogged:
        return HttpResponse('Unauthorized', status=401)
    else:
        index = request.GET.get('id', 0)
        petitiontext = request.GET.get('texto', '')
        petitiontext = petitiontext.strip()
        todaynoformat = datetime.now()
        bookselected = Books.objects.filter(pk=index).first()
        actualwait = Waits.objects.filter(book=bookselected).order_by('ordernum').first()
        if not actualwait:
            response = 'MAL: No hay nadie en espera'
        else:
            profilewaiting = actualwait.profile
            if profilewaiting.pk == profilelogged.pk and actualwait.writting == 1:
                newfragment = Fragments(profile=profilelogged, book=bookselected, date=todaynoformat.isoformat(), texto=petitiontext)
                newfragment.save()
                newtextfull = bookselected.text+" "+petitiontext
                bookselected.text = newtextfull
                bookselected.save()
                actualwait.writting = 2
                actualwait.save()
                response = bookselected.text
            else:
                response = 'MAL: No eres el siguiente en la lista o no estas activado para escribir'
        return HttpResponse(response)
```

Forget about the waiting thing, its some waitlist i used to check if the user is able to submit fragments or not and thats working good.

Any thoughts on why book is not saving to DB? I'm using this object.save() method in other functions and its working, but here it doesn't.

Thanks.

Comment: Likely because the `if profilewaiting.pk == profilelogged.pk and actualwait.writting == 1:` is not satisfied.

Comment: It's satisfied because the newfragment is saved to DB

Comment: use `print()` to see what values you have in variables and which part of code is executed. It is called "print debugging'. OR learn how to use real debugger.

Comment: In the response return I'm getting the new text value of the book, but when I inspect the database through phpmyadmin, no changes on book, but fragments are saved.

Comment: what do you have in `newtextfull` ? Maybe it doesn't change. It adds text from `petitiontext` to `newtextfull` - did you check what you have in `petitiontext `? Maybe `petitiontext` is always empty.

Comment: Every values is fullfilled and right in the response = bookselected.text (after changing the text) the response is ok, the previus text and the new fragment concated, but it doesnt save to DB. I check what i have in petitiontext because it saves the fragment to DB with that text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my bad.

I was trying to update same object on two different functions. So I had to figure out how to update it on one unique function and that's the solution.

Thanks anyway.